Mixed bracket types. Is this json or something else?
I am trying to parse data from a URL. I think it looks like json but I'm not sure. The URL also doesn't end in .json (something like https://google.com/file).
The format of the data on the page looks like this:
[
 {
  "id":"47",
  "firstName": "agent",
  "secondName": "47",
  "assassin": "false"
 }
]

Its the mix of square and curly brackets that's making me unsure what the format is.

This response will not be parsed as JSON object. JSON object starts with "{" and Ends with "}".  square brackets are for array data type. but array can be a value of key. e.g {"output":[{"success":"yes"}, {"anyError":"no"},{"wantMore":"yes"]}

This is valid JSON.

What you show is a valid JSON array.
